# How to change component inside of render with a button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, components

I'm new at programming at all especially in ReactJS. Actually I'm running into a problem.

I just wanna change the page. As simple as it sounds for me it is a 2 day Google-Search-Nothing-Found-Adventure without fun.

I made a component called `<Frontpage />`
It renders directly in the beginning but I want to change it with a click on a button.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Frontpage from './Frontpage'
import Question from './components/Question'


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      showComponent: true,
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.showComponent) {
      return <Question />
    } else {
      console.log("Something went wrong!")
    }
    // console.log("The button was clicked!")
    // document.getElementById('page')
    // document.getElementsByClassName('App-Header')
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <div id="page">
              <Frontpage />
            </div>
              <button id="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Los geht's</button>
          </header>
        </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

When I click it, it always says: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

I tried a lot but nothing worked.

Comment: You need to bind handleClick in constructor. Check the docs for an example https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: check [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) if you need to change component based on page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Change you `handleClick` function to an arrow function and render the component based on the state.

**Update**: notice that i have used a `Fragment` to wrap the `button` and `Question` elements/components

```
import React,{Fragment} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Frontpage from './Frontpage'
import Question from './components/Question'


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      showComponent: false,
    }
  }

  handleClick =()=> {
     this.setState({showComponent:true})
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <div id="page">
              {this.state.showComponent? <Fragment><Question /><button id="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Los geht's</button></Fragment> : <Frontpage /> }
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks!! This helped a lot and worked.
There is just one issue left: The button is still there on my next page.

EDIT: I reused the button, on click @ ```<Frontpage />``` it turns to "Next" on the ```<Question /> component.

Comment: @minternational did you managed to get it working?. please accept the answer if its working

Comment: Yes, thanks. And sorry for waiting for this. I'm new here and don't know the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the `handleClick` to your `class component` or in other case, use an arrow function:
To **bind** the method at the bottom of your `state` inside the `constructor` add this :

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

To use the **arrow function** change the syntax of your method as:

```
this.handleClick = () => {
    if (this.state.showComponent) {
      return <Question />
    } else {
      console.log("Something went wrong!")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Frontpage from './Frontpage'
import Question from './components/Question'


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    // Start with a hide component
    this.state = {
      showComponent: false,
    }
    //  Binding your function
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const { showComponent } = this.state;
    // Use state to trigger a re-render
    this.setState({
      showComponent: !showComponent;
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { showComponent } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <div id="page">
            {
              // Conditionally render a component
              showComponent
              ? (<Question />)
              : (<Frontpage />)
            }
          </div>
          <button id="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Los get's</button>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it renders the ```<Question />``` component additionally and over the ```<Frontpage />``` component.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
import Question from './components/Question'


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      showComponent: true,
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ showComponent: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { showComponent } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <div id="page">
              <Frontpage />
            </div>
            { showComponent ? <Question /> : null }
              <button id="button" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Los geht's</button>
          </header>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```